# FlowJS: types inheritance

Tags: inheritance, intersection, flowtype, type-alias

I'm testing FlowJS for my project, and I have an issue with [Type Aliases](https://flowtype.org/docs/syntax.html#type-aliases).

I build a web SDK for an API: I have an `Helper` class with this method:

```
class Helper {
    find(filters:PaginationOptions = {}) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

`PaginationOptions` is a basic FlowJS type:

```
type PaginationOptions = {
  start?:string,
  end?:number,
};
```

I also have an helper for Users, inheriting from `Helper`:

```
class UsersHelper extends Helper {
    find(filters:UsersFilterOptions = {}) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

`UsersFilterOptions` is a FlowJS type "extending" `PaginationOptions`:

```
type UsersFilterOptions = {
  username?:string,
  city?:string,
} & PaginationOptions;
```

I use here an [Intersection](https://flowtype.org/docs/union-intersection-types.html) so that my users filters should also accept `start` and `end` properties.

It seems that my IDE (PHPStorm) does not like my `find()` method from my class `UsersHelper`, it keeps telling me that:

> Incompatible override, should have type 'PaginationOptions'

Well... I know, that's why `UsersFilterOptions` has an intersection with `PaginationOptions`.

But FlowJS also shows me two others warnings:

> Flow: property `username`. Property not found in object literal
>   Flow: property `city`. Property not found in object literal

I don't understand why I have these errors : these properties are defined as optional...

Do you have any suggestions for fixing these three errors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @nat-mote May I know why tag `flow-js` has been removed? This question is totally about `flow-js`, it's quite a non-sense for me to remove this tag...

Comment: Look at the description for that tag, it's for a different project that's not the flow type checker. The tag for what you want is flowtype: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/flow-js/info

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 3):

When you override a method, it's arguments should be supertypes of corresponding arguments in base class, so you can do this:

```
class A {
  test(x: number) {
  }
}

class B extends A {
  test(x: number | string) {
  }
}
```

But you can't do this:

```
class A {
  test(x: number | string) {
  }
}

class B extends A {
  test(x: number) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply :) This behavior is quite strange in my opinion, but why not... Any idea how to solve my issue and make the compiler happy?